# React JS + Axios return undefined first

Tags: reactjs, axios, undefined

I trying make an axios get from context file into function and call this from component to return data.

Context file:

```
const getPets = async () => {
await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/pets?populate=*')
  .then((res) => {
    return res.data
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
 })}
```

Component file:

```
const [pets, setPets] = useState([])

useEffect( () => {
setPets(getPets())},[])

return (console.log(pets))
```

The return value is undefined and i don't know why.
Can we help me please?

Tks!

Answer (score 2):

Modify getPets():

```
const getPets = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/pets? populate=*');
    return res.data;
}
```

getPets() returns a promise

```
useEffect(() => {
    getPets().then(res => setPets(res));
}, []);

return (
    <>
        {pets?.map(pet => { /* some JSX */})}   
    </>
);
```

Comment: Thaks for your answer. I try this and still returns undefined in component file return.

Comment: That is because you are returning the result of the function call `return (console.log(pets))` -- it writes `pets` into the console, but returns undefined. You might want `return pets;`. In this case the component will return twice (since useEffect is async). To prevent that you might also want to use `useLayoutEffect()` instead, but ususally it is not necessary

Comment: Ok, i undertand. But in return i need execute a map function to render data and still doesn't work. Sorry.

Comment: Modified my answer. Please check

Comment: Into the return of component i have this: {pets.map((pet, index) => (console.log(pet)))} and in browser give me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: Ok, use optional chain (question mark): `pets?.map(...)`

Comment: I try with pets?
No error but not console log.

Comment: You could insert `console.log(pets)` just before `return`

Comment: Yes. If i put console.log(pets) before return, in browser i get undefined value of the console log.

Comment: Let's check if the request returns the value. May be there is a typo in the URL -- space after ? `http://localhost:1337/api/pets? populate=*`. Please check.
You can also check Network tab to see if the request returns anything. Or add `console.log(res);` in getPets before return

Comment: Yes. If i put the endpoint url in browser i see the json data ok and if i put a console log into the getPets method (in context file) in then, print this ok. The problem is that this data don´t see in component, drop undefined.

Comment: Could you please proovide json data you see?

Comment: Capture of json: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13p2hWtB9fsypwbXTIMkl6Y1d-PHw9_Ij/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide the whole Context file.

Comment: ClientsContext.jsx: https://codeshare.io/N3YZZV
Dashboard.jsx: https://codeshare.io/0glVVv

Comment: Well, let's see. For Context to be available in `<Dashboard />`, `<Dashboard />` has to be wrapped in provider. In you case `<Dashboard />` should be inside the `<ClientsList />`. Seems it is not, because ClientsList is not exported from the module. Also, I'd try to extract getPets in separate file outside the Context and check.